# Verb before noun

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, subject-auxiliary-inversion

> Constants and variables of a certain type can't be declared again with the same name, nor can they be altered to store different types.

After 'nor' why 'can' is used first instead of 'they'?
I feel like it should be 'nor they can be...'

Comment: "Nor" is negative and hence triggers subject-auxiliary inversion. So we have  the inverted "nor can they be" but not the uninverted *"nor they can be".

Comment: This answer to http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80064/only-by-defending-against-threats-will-you-be-able-to-carry-out-your-strategies should be useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/80071/3281

Comment: @Damkerng T. There is no mention of fronted "nor" in that link, so how can it be relevant.

Comment: @BillJ Fair enough. (It's only relevant to those who know why it's relevant, and that means that the reader has to know that inversion applies to both negative and restrictive expressions, which makes the inversion happens in both *nor* (e.g., *..., nor do I care*) and *only* (e.g., *Only after ... would I ...*).) Still, I think we already have a similar question. (I wrote one in http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26817/why-are-the-subject-and-the-verb-inverted-after-the-conjunction-as, but it was about *as*, not *nor*.)

Comment: Hey @DamkerngT., would you mind posting the essential gist of your comment as an answer? I'd love to upvote it. :)

Comment: @Omnidisciplinarianist As you wish! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that in most English clauses, the subject comes before the verb. Then again, [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28linguistics%29) is quite common. The two main types of inversion in English are subject-verb inversion (*Into the room will come a unicorn*--an example on the Wikipedia page), and **subject-auxiliary inversion** (also known as SAI). Your example sentence is an example of SAI.

Subject-auxiliary inversion (SAI) should not be new to you, because it happens in questions (e.g., *Will you help him?*), but SAI also happens after negative (*never, not, nor*) or restrictive (think *only, hardly, seldom*, and such) expressions. For example:

> ***Never have we been*** more close.
>   ***Not until*** he had finished his coffee **did he consider** food.
>   ***Only after*** two billion years **did the first cell emerge**.
>   ***Seldom have I heard*** such nonsense.

In your example, *nor* triggers the subject-auxiliary inversion. That's why it is *..., nor can they be altered to store different types*.

For more information, see our questions tagged [subj-aux-inversion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subj-aux-inversion).

Comment: *Into the room will come a unicorn* is really subject–dependent inversion.  In this example, the subject *a unicorn* has switched places with *into the room*, a dependent of the verb; the subject hasn't actually switched places with the verb.  See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, starting on page 1385.