# Only once did I see any elephant

Tags: determiners, subject-auxiliary-inversion, negative-inversion

I stumbled on this sentence in a book called ["Going Solo"](https://books.google.com/books?id=90v0Hg0Mq90C&pg=PT84), but it doesn't look grammatically correct to me:

> Only once did I see any elephant.

Please explain to me how does it work.

Comment: I think it's called [fronting](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/frontingterm.htm) (with [do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)). The basic sentence is ***I saw an elephant only once*** (note that your use of ***any*** is non-idiomatic here), and if you want to move the (adverbial) element ***only once*** to the front, you'd often include do-support for the main verb ***see***. But note that *Only once I saw an elephant* is also syntactically valid - it's just idiomatically unlikely in most contexts. But so is your example (they're both stilted / poetic ways of speaking).

Comment: Can you please give us some more context? As it is, we don't have much to go on.

Comment: An old answer of mine should be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/101644/3281. (An example sentence: *Only after two billion years did the first cell emerge*.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers If the watcher had seen several elephant on one occasion, surely he/she might legitimately say: *Only once did I see any elephant*.

Comment: @Gilani Could you please edit your question to point out the specific part of the sentence you're curious about?  Is it the grammatical structure with *only once*, or is it the use of *any*?  What in particular makes you suspect the sentence might be grammatically incorrect?  Once you've edited the question, we'll be able to reopen the question so you can get an answer that addresses your specific concerns.

Comment: *Only* is not actually a negative, but it's semantically and grammatically related to the phenomenon of negative inversion (CGEL pages 95–96), so I thought the tag was appropriate here.

Comment: @Ronald Sole: To my mind, your use of ***elephant*** there as a "mass, collective, uncountable noun" is pretty much archaic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As a frequent visitor to African game parks and exchanger of animals sightings news with fellow visitors, I respectfully disagree.

Comment: @Ronald Sole: Maybe "archaic" is a bit strong. And I don't deny your usage could still be *relatively* common among the small set of Anglophones closely involved with elephants (as with the great white hunters of yore). But it's definitely [a minority, declining usage.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pictures+of+elephant%2Cpictures+of+elephants&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpictures%20of%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpictures%20of%20elephants%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Elephant* is only non-count when it's a material or foodstuff.  It's count with a zero plural (in the plural form *elephant*) when it's treated as a game animal (as in *hunting elephant*).  *Elephant* is a singular count noun when used with *any*, which can determine both singular and plural NPs; it is not non-count, nor is it a typo.

Comment: @snailplane♦: I know how it works. I'm just saying that "treated as a game animal" reflects an outdated perspective *and* syntax for mainstream Anglophones. I fully accept there will be a small number of people like Ronald (who perhaps see themselves as the ethical descendants of colonial hunters) for whom the usage is still "natural". Interestingly, Google Books has one instance of zero plural ***shot several elephant in*** and none for ***saw several elephant in***. But there are a couple of ***shot several elephants in***, and nine ***saw several elephants in***. Regular plural is winning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I think it would be quite rare to treat *elephant* as a game animal with a zero plural in most contexts.  But it's not relevant to the OP's *any elephant*, which is a normal use of *elephant* as a singular count noun and is fine.  The discussion you and Ronald are bringing up is a red herring, so I want to distinguish it from the OP's *any elephant*.  That's what I was trying to do when I left my comment – sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @snailplane♦: Now I'm intrigued. You say OP's context is a valid use of singular, but I think that's not a credible interpretation with ***any***. I know you could say *I didn't see any cow* if someone just said *Help! Where's my cow?* But if he'd asked *Where are my **cows**?,* I really think you should use the plural in your reply. Whatever - It might be starchy, but *Only once did I ever meet any Frenchmen* is at least *credible* to me, whereas *Only once did I ever meet any **Frenchman*** sounds so weird I think it could *only* occur facetiously.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It still sounds perfectly natural to my ear to say: *On our trip we saw elephant, hippo and buffalo* rather than pluralising them. (My Irish ancestors only ever hunted black and tans - and were hunted by them in return.)

Comment: @Ronald Sole: I don't actually remember whether at time of posting my *first* comment I may have thought you were a non-native speaker (it doesn't seem likely *now!* :). But I certainly don't want to imply *criticism* of those native speakers who include the zero plural ***elephant*** in their natural speech. You speak how you speak, it's a historically established usage I'm well aware of, and that's fine by me. But I don't think OP was aware of the implications, or used this particular zero plural knowingly, and I don't think most learners *should* need or want to know and use the form here.

Comment: @snailplane♦: It seems to me this is a valid question, and the "answer" OP seeks is pretty much covered in the above comments. I don't fully understand your position here (it doesn't look like a credible "singular count noun" usage to me, though perhaps there's room for debate on that point). Anyway, I think it *is* about an unusual zero plural usage, and I'm prepared to post an answer to that effect. So I've voted to reopen, and currently I'm minded to think I'll escalate it to meta if necessary. But I'd rather you just cancelled your unilateral "mod hammer" closevote, if that's okay by you.

Comment: ... I realise OP *could* have responded to requests for clarification, but when considered from a competent native speaker's perspective the fact of it being ***elephant*** rather than ***elephants*** is the *only* "unusual" aspect of the example text. It therefore seems reasonable to assume that's the aspect OP is concerned about, whether explicitly stated or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I reopened it, but it's still not clear to me whether they're asking about *any elephant* (which I agree is interesting) or the fronting of a phrase with *only* and accompanying subject–auxiliary inversion (*I saw an elephant only once* → *Only once did I see an elephant*), so maybe you could talk about both in your answer.

Comment: @snailplane♦: Ty. I'll pass on the full dissection of *I haven't seen **a cow / any cow / any cows*** for now - it's definitely interesting, but it's probably a bit too complex for ELL. I say "probably" because as of right now even *I'm* not completely clear on what's going on there, so I think it's safest if I mainly restrict myself to exactly and only the reason why ***elephant*** is actually a valid (but at least *slightly* unusual) alternative to ***elephants*** in OP's exact citation.

Answer (score 2):

From my initial comment to the answer, *I think it's called [fronting](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/frontingterm.htm) (with [do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)*). That's because I assume the basic sentence is *I saw an elephant* - converted to *I **did see** an elephant*, and modified by adverbial ***only once***, which would more naturally occur at the end. But most likely that's not what confuses OP - native speakers might find the construction a little "poetic", but it's very specifically the ***any elephant*** usage that might cause many of us [to do a double-take.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+a+double+take)

I initially assumed that OP's usage there should have been either singular ***an elephant*** or plural ***any elephants***. Because this is a *learners'* site, I mistakenly ignored the possibility that it was a relatively uncommon use of a [zero-plural noun form](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/zeroplterm.htm). But after looking at the actual source, it's clear the writer has perfectly good command of English, so *it's not a mistake*.

Many "biological category" nouns in English can take the zero-plural form. For some *(deer, sheep, cod)* this is effectively the *only* credible plural today. For others, such as *fish / fishes*, the "regular" plural is either archaic, or restricted to "scientific" references to multiple *types* of different fish.

But OP's citation is in fact a valid (but [declining](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20herd%20of%20elephant%2Ca%20herd%20of%20elephants&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20herd%20of%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20herd%20of%20elephants%3B%2Cc0)) zero plural, similar to *a herd of deer, a herd of sheep*, etc. It's primarily associated with contexts where the animal/s is/are thought of collectively as a type of game to be hunted (hopefully, *in order to be photographed* today), or livestock to be cared for.

---

I found this on [hatmandu.net](http://hatmandu.net/) (where 'base plural only' = 'always uses zero plural form')

> Eric Partridge (of Usage and Abusage fame) regards this as a snobbish usage by big-game hunters; and further that the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL) includes *deer, moose, sheep, bison, salmon, grouse, pike, trout, fish, swine* as ‘base plural only’, then *elk, quail and reindeer* as ‘base or regular plural’, and *elephant, giraffe, lion, partridge and pheasant* as ‘base plural restricted’.

My advice to learners would be to avoid "optional" zero-plural forms completely. Even though *some* native speakers would recognize *a herd of elephant* as valid, not everyone will. And if you use the form indiscriminately you might end up producing, say, *a herd of horse* (which I don't think *anyone* would accept).

Comment: This answer is _extremely_ technical, and I can barely understand it myself. I find it hard to believe that's it would be useful to a learner.

Comment: @David: I suppose the bottom line for native speakers is *Would you expect the plural **elephants** in OP's cited text?* Or more specifically for learners, ***Why** are at least some native speakers happy with 'apparently singular' **elephant**?* To which my answer is approximately *They have their reasons, but you don't really want to know. Stick to regular plurals where they're available.*